# Recyclerview cuts from top margin

Tags: android, view, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

[image: Image Description]I am using recyclerview and one EditText which is used for filter in recyclerview. I have used adjustpan for viewing Edittext on top of soft keyboard. When keyboard is opened my recyclerview goes up and cuts the first row almost half.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/relativemain"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#fff">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_below="@+id/include"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include2"
        layout="@layout/setting_header"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/notifyBlue"
        layout="@layout/notify_bluetooth"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/include"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/header"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/include2"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:id="@+id/recycleView"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etSearch"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/include" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgbackbutton"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_purpleforbutton"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_button"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etSearch"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/rlFooter"
        layout="@layout/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pBarMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <com.StampWallet.customClasses.FocusClearingEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etSearch"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rlFooter"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hint="type to search a store"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution.
What I have done to solve this.. I have added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to my activity in Manifest.

And hide and show my header and user info view as soft keyboard opens and close....

**My EditText listner for search**

```
etSearch.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                if (b) {
                    if (include != null)
                        include.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (include2 != null)
                        include2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (notifyView != null)
                        notifyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    if (include != null)
                        include.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (include2 != null)
                        include2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

**This solved my problem**

Answer (score 0):

Adding "adjustresize" to your manifest will solve the problem

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: Thanks I will try this.

Comment: I tried this but changes the way the recyclerview display. It hides between my header and footer. My header almost cover 20% of my screen and my footer cover about 8% of screen. So this is not helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute to your AndroidManifest.xml file.This will solve your problem.

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivityName"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

Comment: I have done this 
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

I think you don't understand my problem. I have done this then after i faces problem. When i open Edittext my  Recyclerview goes up and cuts first row almost half

Comment: @JadavLalit can you put Screen shot of it?